# Boost vs. .Net random number generators

Tags: c++, boost, random, f#

I developed the same algorithm (Baum-Welch for estimating parameters of a hidden Markov model) both in F# (.Net) and C++. In both cases I developed the same test that generates random test data with known distribution and then uses the algorithm to estimate the parameters, and makes sure it converges to the known right answer.

The problem is that the test works fine in the F# case, but fails to converge in the C++ implementation. I compared both algorithms on some real-world data and they give the same results, so my guess is that the generation of the test data is broken in the C++ case. Hence my question: What is the random number generator that comes with .Net 4 (I think this is the default version with VS2010)?

In F# I am using:

```ml
let random = new Random()
let randomNormal () = //for a standard normal random variable
    let u1 = random.NextDouble()
    let u2 = random.NextDouble()
    let r = sqrt (-2. * (log u1))
    let theta = 2. * System.Math.PI * u2
    r * (sin theta)
//random.NextDouble() for uniform random variable on [0-1]
```

In C++ I use the standard Boost classes:

```c
class HmmGenerator
{
public:
    HmmGenerator() :
         rng(37), //the seed does change the result, but it doesn't  make it work
         normalGenerator(rng, boost::normal_distribution<>(0.0, 1.0)),
         uniformGenerator(rng, boost::uniform_01<>()) {}//other stuff here as well
private:
    boost::mt19937 rng;
    boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, 
                           boost::normal_distribution<> > normalGenerator;
    boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, 
                           boost::uniform_01<> > uniformGenerator;
};
```

Should I expect different results using these two ways of generating random numbers?

EDIT: Also, is the generator used in .Net available in Boost (ideally with the same parameters), so I could run it in C++ and compare the outcomes?

Comment: (+1) interesting question. Few questions - 1.What do you mean by C++ implementation does not converge (to what)? 2.How many samples are you drawing for your experiment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Hence my question: What is the random number generator that comes with .Net 4 (I think this is the default version with VS2010)?

From [the documentation on `Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx)

> The current implementation of the Random class is based on Donald E. Knuth's subtractive random number generator algorithm. For more information, see D. E. Knuth. "The Art of Computer Programming, volume 2: Seminumerical Algorithms". Addison-Wesley, Reading, MA, second edition, 1981.

.

> Should I expect different results using these two ways of generating random numbers?

The Mersenne-Twister algorithm you're using in C++ is considered very respectable, compared to other off-the-shelf random generators.

I suspect any discrepancy in your codes lie elsewhere.

Comment: Do you know if it is available in Boost (with the same parameters ideally)?

Comment: @Grzenio It's hard to tell.  But it seems that you can implement the [mt algorithm in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166408)

Comment: @Grzenio : [`boost::random::knuth_b`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost/random/knuth_b.html) uses the same algorithm as `System.Random`, though the distribution works differently in .NET so you won't get the same output, even with the same seed.